# Disabled option in button is not being changed dynamically

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I am trying to set the disabled property in a button based on a value i am setting OnInitialized. But the button remains disabled even when EnableRegistration is set to true OnInitialized. How to do toggle the disabled property based on the EnableRegistration?

```
@page "/course/register"

<h3 class="my-5">Course Registration</h3>

<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-info">
        <p class="fw-bold">People who register for full course will be given priority over individual module registrations. 
            After registration, look for an email from us to see if you got in and instructions to pay the course fee.
            Registrations will open at 6:00 PM on March 20th.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class=row>
    <div class="col-6">
        <button onclick="Register" id="fullcourse" disabled="@(EnableRegistration == true ? "false": "true")" class="btn btn-primary">Register for Full Course</button>
        
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <button onclick="Register" id="fullcourse" disabled="@(EnableRegistration == true ? "false": "true")" class="btn btn-secondary">Register for First Module</button>
    </div><br/>
        @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Message))
        {
            <p>@Message</p>
        }
    </div>
</div>


@code {
    public bool EnableRegistration;

    public bool Registered = false;

    public string Message = "";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var registrationDateTime = new DateTime(2022, 3, 15, 6, 33, 0);

        if(Registered == false && (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, registrationDateTime) == 1 || DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, registrationDateTime) == 0))
        {
            EnableRegistration = true;
        }
    }

    public void Register()
    {
        Message = "Registered";
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
<button id="fullcourse" disabled="@(!EnableRegistration)"  class="btn btn-primary">Register for Full Course</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
 disabled="@(EnableRegistration == true ? "false": "true")"
```

with

```
 disabled="@(!EnableRegistration)"
```

HTML does not support `="true"` but Blazor does. In the end result you need either just `disabled` or an empty string.  The razor compiler arranges that for you.